# Creating a Secure Key Hash Delete Link

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, security, laravel-5

What would be the best way to create a secure, temporary Delete File Link?

Say if there is no user account, but someone uploads a file and later wants to delete it.

A delete link is generated for them with a key hash:
 `example.com\page\myfile?delete=4Qcp4wTq2UQFR3NiRpGgXCsgQVqT`

If the query hash matches the one in the database, then PHP/Laravel will delete the file and DB record:

```
File::delete($file);
$record->delete();
```

Google Drive uses a 28 random character url for secure file sharing. That's where I got the idea, but I'm not sure if that's how it's actually supposed to be done or if there are more steps required.

How likely is it that someone or a bot can guess that url or visit it by accident?
Should the key hash also match a session id and then no longer be active after session expires?

Comment: 28 characters from [a-zA-Z0-9] is 1.5380389e+50 possible combinations. Good luck guessing that.

Comment: @BrokenBinary Is it possible for a bot to just run through random combinations until it hits one by accident?

Comment: Yes, but it is very unlikely. If 1 million of your 28 character tokens existed, then the odds of a bot finding one by accident is still 1 in 6.5017861e-45. If you wanted to make it even more unlikely you could just use a longer token.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO if you have no user account (so no authentication) a token in the querystring is a good solution, probably the only one.

If the token is long enough it's very very unlikely someone have time and resources to spend for guessing your token. At this point the only weakness is token distribution to users (i.e. mails can be read by others).

If you need tokens to expire just add a field "expire_at", in the same table you store tokens, to check for token validity. Session can be lost if someone remove cookies so I would not use it.